# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'fun.<locals>.BPM'

Tags: python, hilos, pickle

Me encuentro trabajando con threading para multiproceso, y deseo correr a la vez dos procesos donde uno muestra un menu de usuario y otro recolecta informacion de sensores, esta informacion la estoy simulando con la funcion random. El primero no me da problemas al usar threading, pero el segundo que es el siguiente:

```
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time
import threading

def fun():
    class BPM:

        def __init__(self,nombre, valorBPM, valorTEMP, valorO2, fecha):
            self.nombre=nombre
            self.valorBPM=valorBPM
            self.valorTEMP=valorTEMP
            self.valorO2=valorO2
            self.fecha=fecha

        def __str__(self):
            return "Paciente:{} BPM:{} TEMP:{} O2:{} Fecha:{}".format(self.nombre, self.valorBPM, self.valorTEMP, self.valorO2, self.fecha)

    class listapmedicionBPM:

        paciente=[]

        def __init__(self):

            medicionpaciente=open("ficheroExterno","ab+")
            medicionpaciente.seek(0)

        def agregarpersona(self, p):
            self.paciente.append(p)
            self.guardarpacienteenficheroexterno()

        def guardarpacienteenficheroexterno(self):
            medicionpaciente=open("ficheroExterno","wb")
            pickle.dump(self.paciente, medicionpaciente)
            medicionpaciente.close()
            del(medicionpaciente)

        def mostrarinfoficherosexternos(self):
            for p in self.paciente:
                print(p)

    miLista=listapmedicionBPM()
    paciente= 'Carlos'

    while (True):
        time.sleep(1.0)
        medidaBPM = str(random.randint(60,90))
        medidaTEMP= str(random.randint(30,38))
        medidaO2  = str(random.randint(20,80))
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d ')
        
        p=BPM(paciente, medidaBPM, medidaTEMP, medidaO2, now)
        miLista.agregarpersona(p)
        miLista.mostrarinfoficherosexternos()

t1=threading.Thread(name="hilo_1", target=fun, args=())
t1.start()
```

Muestra un error constante que aparece si lo corro en conjunto con otros procesos o si lo corro solo:

```
Exception in thread hilo_1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\Desktop\infoPermanente.py", line 54, in fun
    miLista.agregarpersona(p)
  File "C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\Desktop\infoPermanente.py", line 31, in agregarpersona
    self.guardarpacienteenficheroexterno()
  File "C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\Desktop\infoPermanente.py", line 35, in guardarpacienteenficheroexterno
    pickle.dump(self.paciente, medicionpaciente)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'fun.<locals>.BPM'
```

Estoy corriendo el segundo proceso solo ya que quería identificar de donde proviene el error, pero no logro entender porque aparece este.

Comment: Para poder hacer `pickle` de una instancia, su clase tiene que estar definida global en el módulo, no local en una función.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces de que forma puedo hacer que ese codigo se procese con multiprocesing? o como podria corregir lo de la clase? Hay forma de corregirlo?

Comment: Tienes que mover la definición de la clase `BPM` y `listapmedicionBPM` fuera de `fun`, al nivel más alto.

Comment: Pero entonces como podria hacer que se activen usando threading con el comando t1=threading.Thread(name="hilo_1", target=fun, args=()) ya que por mi proyecto necesito activarlo en multiproceso.

Comment: Roberto. Las clases pueden estar definidas en cualquier parte. Si no fuera asi, tampoco podrias ocupar clases definidas en las librerias de Python. Definir una clase e instanciar un objeto de esa clase son operaciones separadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una de las restricciones de `pickle` es que solo puede serializar clases
que se puedan importar. Para eso cada clase que quieras usar con `pickle`
debe estar al nivel más alto del archivo (al nivel de módulo). Teniendolo
en cuenta, este es el código:

```
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time
import threading

class BPM:

    def __init__(self,nombre, valorBPM, valorTEMP, valorO2, fecha):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.valorBPM=valorBPM
        self.valorTEMP=valorTEMP
        self.valorO2=valorO2
        self.fecha=fecha

    def __str__(self):
        return "Paciente:{} BPM:{} TEMP:{} O2:{} Fecha:{}".format(self.nombre, self.valorBPM, self.valorTEMP, self.valorO2, self.fecha)

class listapmedicionBPM:

    paciente=[]

    def __init__(self):

        medicionpaciente=open("ficheroExterno","ab+")
        medicionpaciente.seek(0)

    def agregarpersona(self, p):
        self.paciente.append(p)
        self.guardarpacienteenficheroexterno()

    def guardarpacienteenficheroexterno(self):
        medicionpaciente=open("ficheroExterno","wb")
        pickle.dump(self.paciente, medicionpaciente)
        medicionpaciente.close()
        del(medicionpaciente)

    def mostrarinfoficherosexternos(self):
        for p in self.paciente:
            print(p)

def fun():
    miLista=listapmedicionBPM()
    paciente= 'Carlos'

    while (True):
        time.sleep(1.0)
        medidaBPM = str(random.randint(60,90))
        medidaTEMP= str(random.randint(30,38))
        medidaO2  = str(random.randint(20,80))
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d ')

        p=BPM(paciente, medidaBPM, medidaTEMP, medidaO2, now)
        miLista.agregarpersona(p)
        miLista.mostrarinfoficherosexternos()

t1=threading.Thread(name="hilo_1", target=fun, args=())
t1.start()
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias compañero, me funcionó.